# Yii2: how to Disable submit information and send data when pressing Enter

Tags: yii, yii2

i want use tags in my form.

tag is complete when client press enter.

but in yii2 if client press enter information is send to controller .
how to disable that ?

[image: tags in yii2]

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'tags')->widget(TagEditor::className(), [
        'tagEditorOptions' => [
            'autocomplete' => [
//                'source' => Url::toRoute(['tag/source'])
            ],
        ]
    ]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>

 <?= $form->field($model, 'fileZ')->fileInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can try [this](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/disable-form-submit-on-enter-keypress.html).

Comment: Duplicate question but see my response below. The (https://github.com/Faryshta/yii2-disable-submit-[Faryshta/yii2-disable-submit-buttons]buttons/blob/master/composer.json) is the best one I have seen and works great.

Comment: @Saltern if you don't mind, can your share the success script for yii2? I using this script [link](http://jsfiddle.net/N9T9e/), but if press enter information is still send to controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is implementing some javascript. You could check which key is typed and if the number matches enter numerical value (13 I believe) than stop it. This is a basic [idea](http://webcheatsheet.com/javascript/disable_enter_key.php).